# Where is music stored in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

So, Rhythmbox completely broke my ipod and corrupted the music libraries.  While I was trying to fix it, I made the mistake of (accidentally) removing all the music via right-click->remove from my library.  Now, I didn't send the music to the trash, which I guess means that it's still on my computer somewhere.  Where's it at?

EDIT:  Absolutely no chance of recovering music from the ipod itself.  The songs are either missing or cut in half due to rhythmbox conveniently crashing on sync.

Comment: Maybe too obvious, but did you look in the 'Music' folder in your home directory?

Comment: That's the thing that I'm lost on.  When I right click on a song in the library I have the options 'Remove' and 'Move to Trash'.  Intuitively I think that 'Remove' (which is what I did) would remove them from rhythmbox and not delete the files, but they aren't under 'Music' and I don't have any other library locations in rhythmbox's dconf thingy

Comment: Try running `find -iname *.mp3` (replace .mp3 with the appropriate extension if needed) in a terminal. If the songs are somewhere in your home folder this should find them.

Comment: @MarkPaskal You're assuming they're MP3 files. Although, I don't own an Apple device, and I could be wrong.

Comment: @MarkPaskal It looks like there's not a secret folder I don't know about, thanks for the tip.  I was experimenting with the 'Remove' function on Rhythmbox;  it doesn't delete the file, but when I originally did it I did it to 200 files at once.  I think it screwed up there.  So they didn't get moved to trash, and they definitely aren't still in the Music folder.  I guess they're gone lol...thanks everybody

Comment: I edited the comment just now. I believe AAC is the correct format to use for apple.

Comment: mine happen to be mp3s, so it's all good

Comment: Ouch. Sorry about your tunes. Are you using an older version of Ubuntu by any chance? I just looked and I don't seem to have an option to just remove songs from the library in 12.10; there's only the option to move to trash.

Comment: 12.04...i guess it was fixed then

Comment: @Anonymouse, no it wasn't. Just lost all my tunes on iPad work when Rhythmbox went down and took my library with it - Ubuntu 12.10. Now no tunes at work and no tunes on the train. Thanks Rhytmbox.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Rhythmbox does not display the source for imported files on the GUI. In case we selected more than a single location *"Multiple locations set"* will be displayed only:

[image]

We can view and change the directories Rhythmbox should monitor for creating the database by running **dconf-editor** (from [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools]) where we can browse to *org/ gnome/ rhythmbox/ rhythmdb/ locations*):

[image]

If this does not reveal the location of our mp3 files we can also perform a search on our file system which can be done with the default **file browser Nautilus**.

We open the location from where we want to find our files. In case we want to scan the whole filesystem including mounted additional drives we open the location *"File System"*. In the *"Search"* line on top we give in an expression to be found in a filename, in this case when we search for mp3-files we may enter *"mp3"*. Note that **wildcards are not supported**:

[image]

Of course we can also perform searches for files from the command line, e.g with the following commands:

```
cd /home # use cd / for the whole file system
find -H -name *.mp3
```

The option `-H` tells find to not follow symbolic links, the option `-name` is case sensitive. If you have mp3 and MP3 files choose option `-iname` instead.